# How can I change the log directory for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default, VS Code (and its extensions) write their logs to

- `%AppData%\Code\Logs\` (on Windows),
- `~/.config/Code/logs/` (on Linux),
- `~/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/` (on MacOS).

How can I configure this, e.g. to write them to a different disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can using the `--user-data-dir <absolute-path>` argument